# How to update column by name in different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have many tables in `Oracle` db .

---

I want to get all the tables which contain fields like `(dep_year or main_year)`

and update them with `2016` value instead of `2014`

How to do something like that in procedure .

Comment: That's an odd requirement... I'd consider re-designing the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query `all_tab_columns`, build your `update` and then `execute immediate` that `update`.

```
begin
   for rc in (select 'update '||table_name || ' set '||column_name||'  = 2016 where '||column_name||' = 2014' as stmt from all_tab_columns where column_name in ('DEP_YEAR', 'MAIN_YEAR'))
    loop
        execute immediate (rc.stmt);
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

For each required column, you can find all tables containing it:

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE column_name = :columnName;
```

with each table name that you just found, execute update query:

```
Execute immediate ('Update ' || table_name || ' set ' || column_name || ' = 2016 where ' || column_name || ' = 2014 ')
```